# Immutability of the class is getting destroyed how to prevent that?

Tags: java, immutability

I have the Student class where i am having final variables and i have 
     variable 'doj' which is of Date type and i have provided getters for 
     them, But in main class i am able to update the variable doj which 
     breaks the immutability property.How can i prevent this ?

Below is the Code:

```
final public class Student {
    final String name;
    final String rollno;
    final Date dob; 

    public Student(String name, String rollno, Date dob) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public final String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public final Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

}

public class StudentMain {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Student s=new Student("john", "1", new Date());
        System.out.println(s.getDob());
        Date d=s.getDob();
        d.setDate(30072019);
        System.out.println(s.getName());
        System.out.println(s.getRollno());
        System.out.println(s.getDob());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the constructor like this.

```
public Student(String name, String rollno, Date dob) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.dob = new Date(dob.getTime());
    }
```

In case of getter method, you have to use like this.

```
public final Date getDob() {
        return new Date(dob.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: could you please explain me how it will not let the value change in the reference in the main class. Date d=s.getDob(); d.setDate(30072019); How it is getting prevented here? @Sambit

Comment: This link will help you. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Date` is mutable object you should make a new `Date` object in your constructor :

```
public Student(String name, String rollno, Date dob) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.rollno = rollno;
            this.dob = new Date(dob.getTime());
}
```

However `java.util.Date` class is deprecated and you should consider using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) - both those classes are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return copies of your internal (immutable) state. You shouldn't expose internal references.

For instance:

```
public final Date getDob() {
    return new Date(dob.getTime());
}
```

Comment: could you please explain me how it will not let the value change in the reference in the main class. Date d=s.getDob();
        d.setDate(30072019); How it is getting prevented here? @michael

Comment: Because then with `s.getDob()` you will get the reference of the copied `Date` and the internal / original `Date` remains safe and unexposed.